# Нет ответа от функции

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток.

Суть в чем: есть некая переменная, которая получает адрес картинки, которая потом обрабатывается функцией и возвращается, но суть в том, что когда происходит возврат, значение становиться нулевым.

Вот код php:

```
<?php 
  $img="http/site.ru/1.img";
  var_dump($img);
  function strReplase($imgThe){
    $imgUrl=str_replace(".jpg","-150x150.jpg",$imgThe);
    return $imgUrl;
   }
  var_dump(strReplase($img);?>
```

В ответ я получаю:

```
string(18)"http/site.ru/1.img"  null
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему не передается значение из функции. Код не совсем живой, поэтому возможны где-то очепятки.

Причем если поставить

```
   return var_dump($imgUrl);
```

то получится

```
 string(18)"http/site.ru/1.img" string(25)"http/site.ru/1-150x150.img"  null
```

то есть функция обрабатывает данные.

Тут просили выложить настоящую функцию.
В данный момент на сайте (конечно, это тест для проверки) я разместил вот такой код:

```
 function srtReplace($img){                    
  $imgUrl=str_replace(".jpg","-150x150.jpg",$img);
  return $ImgUrl;}
 $theOneImg="http://site.ru/one.jpg";
 $oneThumb=srtReplace($theOneImg);
 var_dump($oneThumb);
```

Результат null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Функция должно возвращать значение. Возвращение идет через return $imgUrl; Ваша строка с var_dump возвращает результат выполнения функции var_dump

2) В вызове функции вы передали не ту переменную и не закрыли скобку.

> var_dump(strReplase($img));

---

Вот код:

```
<?php 
  $img="http/site.ru/1.img";
  var_dump($img);
  function strReplase($imgThe){
    $imgUrl=str_replace(".jpg","-150x150.jpg",$imgThe);
    var_dump($imgUrl);
    return $imgUrl;
   }
  var_dump(strReplase($img)); // Тут изменил $imgThe на $img
?>
```

Выводит:

```
string(18) "http/site.ru/1.img"
string(18) "http/site.ru/1.img"
string(18) "http/site.ru/1.img"
```

---

В следующем вашем варианте:

```
function srtReplace($img){                    
  $imgUrl=str_replace(".jpg","-150x150.jpg",$img);
  return $imgUrl; // изменил $ImgUrl на $imgUrl
  }
 $theOneImg="http://site.ru/one.jpg";
 $oneThumb=srtReplace($theOneImg);
 var_dump($oneThumb);
```

Вывод:

```
string(30) "http://site.ru/one-150x150.jpg"
```

Comment: Etki  и  IVsevolod  в пред идушем  почему то не могу найти кнопу добавть коментарии . Не хочу вас оскорблять но все же вы не видите я отредактировал вопрос?  В функции return var_dump(...) я писал только что бы показать что $imgUtl имеет значение но оно не поулчеться через return. Я отредактрировал вопрос потому, что в оригинальном коде  return var_dump(...) не стоит, а стои сразу return $imgUrl и значение выводиться не var_damp функцией. И об этом в коментариях к предидущему ответу писал что это здесь написано для проверки.

Comment: @Sergalas, а я еще раз повторюсь - не бывает так, что в var_dump уходит, а в return не уходит. Уберите var_dump, проверьте три раза, если так и не завелось, выложите реально неработающий код.

Comment: @Sergalas, попробуй код в ответе, что выведет? Еще раз, с новым кодом

Comment: Все, я нашел, в чем ошибка, ставлю вам ответ. За настойчивость спасибо ещё и @Etki.

Answer (score 3):

Ну так то что Вы спрашиваете, то и получаете. 
Так же измените

```
return var_dump($imgUrl);
```

на

```
return $imgUrl;
```

Вы определитесь - Вам или вывести результат в функции надо, или вернуть из неё?

Comment: вы насамом деле дуаете я не пробывал. Вы думаете я выводил только var_dump это я для того что бы проверить и увидеть. Почему и где ошибка.

Comment: @Sergalas, тогда почему у Вас даже в примере изначально неправильный код, если вы знаете об этом?

Comment: Я в примере показал, что вардампом код отрабатывается даже перед передачей, но не передается. Как мне это было отразить? Я могу убрать вардамп в ретурне  - результат не поменяется.

Comment: @Sergalas, это не сишка, тут не бывает, что в выводе в функции что-то есть, но через return не уходит.

Comment: @Sergalas, теперь вам понятно, почему не передается параметр? )

Comment: Etki, и чего делать-то, через глобальную видимость добиваться.

Comment: IVsevolod, нет, конечно, и ваш ответ в абсолюте равен первому и на ввопрос не отвечает.

Comment: @Sergalas, т.е. вас не смущает тот факт, что вы передаете в функцию несуществующую переменную, т.е. **null**? На момент вызова у вас есть только переменная $img.

Comment: @Sergalas поставить обычный return без var_dump